# Relative Path in master page for img tag

Tags: asp.net, relative-path, master-pages

I have a  tag in a master page.
I use this master page in many folders. So the src path of the  tag should be different for each folder.
Here is my code :

```
<img src="images/1.gif" />
```

and I have a folder named "images" and a folder named "Users".
Master Page is in the root, but I use it in Users folder.

How can I set a dynamic address for src?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use an asp:Image tag. You need to add runat="server" in order to use ~ syntax to resolve your URLs.

```
<asp:Image ID="myImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/1.gif" />
```

Comment: Thanks.
It's OK for <img> but another problem is for background-image attribute in <td> tag. like this :
<td style="background-image: images/1.gif;"> </td>
How can I solve it?

Comment: style="background-image: url(<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/1.gif") %>);"

Answer (score 6):

Just use `<img runat="server" src="~/images/1.gif" />`. This is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlimage.src(VS.80).aspx).