# <img> tag in masterpage does not show logo when called from IIS virtual folder?

Tags: asp.net, image, iis, master-pages

It works fine when I dont use virtual folder. My virtual folder is named test which points to an application inside MyDocuments. The path to my App is

```
localhost\test\app\login.aspx
```

Note that if I move the application in the root folder wwwroot and make it an application, it works fine. I tried

```
<img src="logo.jpg" />
<img src="..\logo.jpg" />
<img src="~/logo.jpg" />
<img src="\\test\logo.jpg" />
```

Can it be fixed or should I leave it? My logo.img is in root folder of the application. I move it to \images\ folder as well still does not work.

There is a similar post here [Relative Path in master page for img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506408/777982) which did not solve my problem because it does not use Virtual Folder path.

Edit: I did used  tag also and it did not work too.

```
<asp:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/logo.jpg" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer you have linked to is the way to properly include images and should solve your problem. You should use an `<asp:Image` tag and specify the relative path to this image starting from your virtual directory root.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding runat="server" within the your html img contrl and select the src="" from the intellisense property of the visual studio.

```
                     or
```

Use Asp image server control instead of html img control and set the imageurl attribute from intellisense property of the visual studio.

Hope this will help you...

Comment: I have an <asp:image> tag in use like this. `<asp:Image ID="~/imgLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/logo.jpg" />`. Just wanted to make things simple. Didn't work but good point though.

Comment: @Dave,Then,Check your image path. I guess u might be added image inside a folder within root. If so do not set the ImageUrl attribute of your asp.net Image server control manually. Instead use ctrl+space bar and select the exact image path from there (this is what i meant by intellisense).To see whether the path of the image is correct browse using the virtual directory url (http:// system IP/virtual directory name/Image folder/logo.jpg) directly in browser and see whether you can acces the image.U can try setting this full url as ImageUrl attribute as well (this should definitely work).

Comment: Did exactly that -> `ImageUrl="~/logo.jpg" />`. If I browse to the image using the url technique, it says I do not have permission. Now I have enabled this for other folder which sits inside wwwroot and it does work but not for this. Believe me Microsoft sucks! They don't do thing right, they just get rid of things.

Comment: @Dave, So your image folder is outside root. If it is so you have to definitely give required permissions for that folder. You should set read/write permissions for system account(your login account) and Iuser(iis user) on that folder where you saves images. If this folder is inside root no need for permission (it does have default permissions set). After setting permissions retry the steps of my previous comment.

Comment: well if it can access other files in that folder (like login.asxp), I would assume image should be displayed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the asp:Image, it does all the hard work for you and gets rid of this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `~/logo.jpg` syntax only works in server controls, such as `<asp:Image />`. The `~` is then a shorthand for the root of your web-application.

If your 'test' directory is an application, then the logo should be there to be found.

To troubleshoot these kind of problems, you need to know the mapping between the physical location of your page ('login.aspx') and the url used to call it. A similar mapping will exist between the physical location of your image and the url you need to get it.

You could try to enter the url for that image directly in the browser. When you have a url that succeeds, you can figure out how to refer to that image from your page.
If it's in the same directory, a plain 'logo.jpg' will work. If elsewhere, you need to add some folderpaths ('images/logo.jpg' if it's in a folder named 'images' next to that page).

Comment: Yes I tried that like 40 times in firefox before posting here. Did not work.

Comment: By the way MSFT has thousands of bugs in their products, wont be surprised if this is one too. And they will say "This is standard behavior"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and above solutions worked for me.
I know this is old post.

In Masterpage all you have to do is

> drag and drop Image
>   then go its properties and set the url (You can browse it from there)

Now all my pages have the logo with no issue of finding it.